# Unable to perform left outer join using mongoDB Script

Tags: mongodb, left-join

How do I perform a left outer join while accessing data from multiple collections?
I want to get the details from  collection even if there is no match in DB_Market. Presently if I filter further using  condition, I am able to achieve inner join. However I also need left outer in addition to this.

Sample code

```
 db.new.aggregate([
 { 
    "$lookup": {
                "from": "DB_Market",
                "localField": "var1",
                "foreignField": "var1",
                "as": "collection2_doc"
           }
 },

 {"$unwind": "$collection2_doc" }])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can perform left outer join. When you are doing `$unwind`, make sure **preserveNullAndEmptyArrays** is `true`

```
    db.new.aggregate([
     { 
        $lookup: {
                    "from": "DB_Market",
                    "localField": "var1",
                    "foreignField": "var1",
                    "as": "collection2_doc"
               }
     },

     {$unwind: { path: "$collection2_doc", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }  }

     ])
```